# replace remove command (in Linux - overall) with shred

Tags: environment-variables, rm, replace, shred

short question: as the title suggests, a system-wide shred instead of the command rm

Long question:

I know about the "replace" command,
as well as I could just to rm = shred (or something on those lines)
but i thought - How would I go around by replacing **ALL** sort of **Remove** commands/calls in Linux to shred instead?

Like, not only in CLI - but in GUI (E.g with Thunar as well, instead of deleting or empty recycle bin, Thunar would shred the file (first I guess) (then, maybe send it to recycle bin or just delete it right in there)

Note, when I say replace in overall Linux - I mean for every program/cli/command - which removes/deletes a file (**OR a Directory by the way, e.g recursively**).

If this is possible obviously.

Thanks! //Hope all is well with you all.

As usual, if I have made a mistake somewhere, (not only grammar - but anything else) please, do not hesitate to edit. (Even if you are unsure!) or ask for clarification/details.

Off topic below.

- a side-question (if this is allowed!) How can I tell the "review" program (that reviews a question before it is posted) to review it again?

**NOTE** this is more of a hack than a solution;

I have made a LKM that hooks any "normal" del command and replaces it with a "shred" command; but as said this is more a ""hack"" not an actual, solution.

this is on a test machine by the way, it's too risky to actually use.

and yes it does look like a rootkit someone pointed out :)

Comment: of course I meant  with the short question: a env.variable, like export or in the user's bash rc file.

Comment: you know that GUI likely use directly `unlink(2)` to delete files (that is when not moving to empty bin) ?

Comment: @Archemar I didn't,  :) but I thought (and tested) to hook the commands via an LKM (**this is just.. a "hack" not a actual solution**)  so when you type "rm" or use the gui "del" - you actually use the command `shred -n 500 <file>` but as said, it's a hack/proof-of-concept instead of an actual solution;